# Row-wise Logical operation on numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, logical-operators

I have an numpy.ndarray in the following format:

```
array([[ 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [ 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [ 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       ...,
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

and I want to apply the `XOR` logical operator on elements of each row. i.e. I want an output like in the following format:

```
[[0.],
 [1.],
 [1.],
 ...,
 [1],
 [0],
 [0]]
```

How can I do this in Python ? I know about `np.logical_xor` but I do not know that how I can use it efficiently.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Why is the third-to-last row of your output `[1]`? If you're you sequentially doing xor from left-to-right, shouldn't it be `[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.reduce`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[0., 0., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 0., 0.],
                [0., 1., 0., 0.],
                [1., 0., 0., 1.],
                [1., 1., 1., 1.],
                [1., 1., 1., 1.]])

res = np.logical_xor.reduce(arr, 1).astype(np.int32)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[0 1 1 0 0 0]
```

The function [`np.logical_xor`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html#numpy.logical_or) is an ufunc, as such it has 4 [methods](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#methods), from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> **All ufuncs have four methods.** However, these methods only make sense on scalar ufuncs that take two input arguments and return one
> output argument. Attempting to call these methods on other ufuncs will
> cause a ValueError. The reduce-like methods all take an axis keyword,
> a dtype keyword, and an out keyword, and the arrays must all have
> dimension >= 1.

To apply an ufunc along an axis use `.reduce`:

> Reduces array’s dimension by one, by applying ufunc along one axis.